# Fail to start openvpn server

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup an openvpn server by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openvpn.html) tutorial.

The relevant parts of my server.conf is as below.

```
root@something:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa# cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf | grep "^[^#;]" 
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert something.crt
key something.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

The server fails to start and error messages below are posted in my syslog.

```
Nov 30 21:45:46 mini ovpn-server[8696]: 192.168.0.1:40880 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Nov 30 21:45:46 mini ovpn-server[8696]: 192.168.0.1:40880 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Nov 30 21:45:46 mini ovpn-server[8696]: 192.168.0.1:40880 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Nov 30 21:45:48 mini ovpn-server[8696]: 192.168.0.1:56890 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.0.1:56890, sid=376b5dcc ec4c9266
```

Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if I should post anything else.

Comment: try [this](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/253-tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-check-your-network-connectivity.html) link. It seems a connection problem, maybe due to firewall or missing port forwards

Comment: I already googled that. There is no firewall running. And this is simply the server refusing to start. nmap doesn't give me anything on port 1194.

Comment: Did you get an error when you start server with `service openvpn start` command?

Comment: hey I have a similar problem : http://askubuntu.com/questions/714838/ubuntu-16-04-daily-build-openvpn-wont-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I'm using absolute paths for ca, cert, key and dh I get another error. So I guess that answers this question.